method eth_getLogs in batch triggered rate limit
Anyone have experience in this github repo?
https://github.com/smartcontractkit/smart-contract-examples/blob/main/ccip/offchain/typescript/src/get-status.ts
I'm having some trouble in this function:
const events = await offRampContract.queryFilter(
      offRampContract.filters.ExecutionStateChanged(undefined, messageId)
  );

This error method eth_getLogs in batch triggered rate limit occured here
Anyone can help me with this issue?
I wanna solve this issue.
I'm trying to get CCIP transaction status based on messageID.
I got this issue while getting the status.
